# Is $(-1)^{\varepsilon}=1+i\pi \varepsilon$?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, hypercomplex-numbers

Let $\varepsilon$ be defined as in the dual numbers. Using the standard matrix representation. I tried $(-1)^{\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)}$ and got the following result: $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & i \pi  \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$. But complex numbers should have different representations in matrix form, so I onder if my interpretation is correct.

Comment: You should specify that $\epsilon$ is a matrix, and what type of matrix it is.

Comment: @TobyMak it is the dual unity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number

Comment: You’ve confused people by not providing enough context. $\epsilon$ usually represents a small positive real number, not a dual number.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, $f(\epsilon)=f’(0)\epsilon$ for any differentiable function $f$ defined on a real neighborhood of $0$, when $\epsilon^2=0$. To compute $(-1)^\epsilon$ you need to determine $f$. The matrix expression doesn’t make anything easier here.

Generally, $(-1)^x=e^{x\log(-1)}$ and $\log(-1)=i(2k+1)\pi$ is multivalued. So there is a choice $f_k(x)=e^{xi(2k+1)\pi}$ of function here for each integer. Making a choice here is called choosing a branch cut of $\log$. We have $f_k’(0)=(2k+1)i\pi$, so $f_k(\epsilon)=(2k+1)i\pi\epsilon$. Choosing the branch cut $k=0$ recovers your calculation, but it is one of infinitely many correct answers, as almost always happens with complex exponentials.

Answer (score 0):

No,
$$ (-1)^\epsilon = (e^{i\pi})^{\epsilon} = e^{i\pi\epsilon} = \cos(\pi\epsilon) + i \sin(\pi\epsilon)$$
or, at the very least this is one of the ways that $(-1)^\epsilon$ can be defined. You can get other results using $-1 = e^{i\pi+2n\pi}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$; the function $z^\epsilon$ is a so-called a multi-valued function on a complex plane and can be defined in amny ways.

Comment: But is not $\cos \pi\varepsilon=1$ and $i \sin \pi\varepsilon=i\pi\varepsilon$? There is a rule $f(a+b\varepsilon )=f(a)+bf'(a)\varepsilon$, so your result seems equal to mine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number#Differentiation

Comment: You've never mantion dual numbers in your question. Please update the question so that it would be clear what are you asking about.